# How to log in a user to a remote site using a post request in Django

Tags: django, security, session, authentication, cookies

I have a two sites with different domains but single backend (Django).

As is:

1. Client fill the form on a landing
2. Landing send POST request to Server
3. Server register user
4. User visit main site (server) and fill login form again to log in

To be:

1. Client fill the form on a landing
2. Landing send POST request to Server
3. Server register and login user
4. User visit main site (server) and he is already logged in

What are the ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your registration views function, after registring the user, log him in using the data he entered.

```
user.save() #saving your user to database
user_auth = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=user.password) 
login(request, user_auth)
# Redirect to a success page...
```

Dont forget your import :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
```